# Adding Click Handler On UserControl Breaks Click On Children

Tags: c#, wpf, events

I have a user control that I'm trying to make draggable.  The whole control should be draggable except when you click on buttons or text boxes.  I'm handling the mousedown, mouseup and mousemove events on the usercontrol itself and I can drag by clicking anywhere.  The only issue is now I can't click any buttons on the user control.  Any clue what's going on?

Code is something like this:

```
<UserControl PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown="Popup_PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown" ....STUFF...>
  <!-- CAN'T CLICK THIS -->
  <Button />
<UserControl>
```

Code Behind:

```
public void Popup_PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    mouseDown = true;
    oldMousePosition = this.PointToScreen(e.GetPosition(this));
    this.Popup.Child.CaptureMouse();
}
```

Comment: @GrantWinney It does not.  I'll update the code.

Comment: I'd answered that I thought it was a ZIndex concern, but I take that back. What kind of control is the child of the popup?

Comment: @furkle It is a System.Windows.Controls.Button.

Comment: I didn't read your conversation earlier, before he deleted his account - did you try removing the whole PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown method? Was the button clickable?

Comment: The button worked before adding it.

Comment: Can you try leaving it in, but removing all the code from within the Popup_PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown method in code-behind?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/63822/discussion-between-furkle-and-jeff).

Answer (score 0):

The issue arises when you use CaptureMouse() - this permanently captures all your mouse input on the window, and makes it so that you're unable to click on anything within the Window. I don't know if it's different for you, or if you checked, but it's not (just) that the Button is unclickable - it's that literally everything on the Window is unclickable.

You have to actually do something with the mouse after you've captured it, and then once you finish that, you have to return normal control by calling Mouse.Capture(null). For you, this would probably be best to do in your MouseUp() method.

However, this still leaves the child problem. I can't really think of any way you're going to be able to both capture all mouse click events on a parent control *and* allow them to get to the child control. I suppose you could check the mouse position against the button position, both relative to the UserControl, then route the click event to the Button every time, but this seems a little overelaborate. Is there a reason you can't just add a full-sized Grid to the UserControl with a lower ZIndex than the Button, and just use that to detect if a click was made inside the UserControl but not on the Button?